# Using Excel VBA, how can I save a Word doc with a specified date, including today's date?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a macro that will create an open order report in excel, and then copy/paste "key points" from the spreadsheet into a new Word document. But, I would like to have both the spreadsheet and word doc be saved as a specific file name.

I was successful at getting the spreadsheet to do this, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get the word doc to save this way.

```
 Dim strfileName As String
strfileName= "C:\Users\jrogers3\Documents\VBA TESTS\OOR Summary " & Format(Now(), "mm.dd.yyyy") & ".docm"  
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= “strfileName”, FileFormat _
        :=wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
```

With the above code, the word file is saved as strfileName.

I then removed the strfileName variable and tried:

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= "C:\Users\jrogers3\Documents\VBA TESTS\OOR Summary " & Format(Now(), "mm.dd.yyyy") & ".docm", FileFormat _
        :=wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
```

However, this method did not even save the document.

Comment: In your first code, you mentioned `FileName:= “strfileName”`. When you have value in a variable, you don't need to wrap it in ".  `FileName:= strfileName` is enough. But then you are saying its working? .. Second code looks fine.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the VB Editor? Do you see an error, and if so, what is it? The most obvious possible problem is that the SaveAs2 will fail with error 5152 if the folder "c:\Users\jrogers\Documents\VBA TESTS" does not exist (i.e. the saveas2 will not create that folder).